# Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, sasl

I am having a trouble running flink app on cluster. I am getting below error despite trying all possible options.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is /flink/client_jaas.conf
```

Basically my flink app reads data from topic A and finds events matching some pattern sequence and write output to topic B. I am not able to authenticate to cluster to read events from topicA on performance cluster.

Please let me know what could be wrong here

Comment: Can you shares your JAAS configuration?

Comment: Take a look at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_client_staticjaas and see if your client setup is in line with it.